# PyQt QThread cause main thread to close

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

Hello  i have a problem with creating Thread using the QThread class.
here is my code :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread

class ScriptRunner(QThread):

    def run(self):
        print('test')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = QWidget()
    gui.setFixedSize(400, 400)
    gui.setVisible(True)

    ScriptRunner().start() # this line cause the error

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

when i lunch this code without the `ScriptRunner().start()` line, the gui is working without any problem, but when i do add the line, the gui show up and is hidden very quickly and program is shutdown

I receive this message in the console :

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/karim/upwork/python-qt-rasp/tests/test.py
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change the line:

```
ScriptRunner().start() # this line cause the error
```

to:

```
sr = ScriptRunner()
sr.start()
```

Tested for PyQt4 though, but works.

EDIT:

Another workaround that worked for me:

Instantiating `ScriptRunner` as `ScriptRunner(gui).start()` also works.

Comment: why is that a problem?? these two line are exactly the same as the first one. the second edit worked thanks but do you know why its required to specify a parent for the thread?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure what's the problem with your original approach.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that you must save a reference to the thread that you lunch, in my real world example, i was not saving a reference to the thread in my object, so its was garbage collected by python i think.

```
self.runner = Runner()
```